# Regex with C#: How do I replace a string that matches a specific group

Tags: c#, regex

Given a regex with 2 groups:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^[^{}]*(\\{([^}]*)\\})[^{}]*$"); // group 1 matches {exp} (with braces)
                                                          // group 2 matches exp   (without braces)
```

How do I replace a match in the first group?

```
string inputStr = "mystring{valueToRaplace}"
string s = regex .Replace(inputStr, m => ???);
```

For instance I want to specify whether to match and replace `{valueToRaplace}` (group 1) or `valueToRaplace` (group 2).

Comment: You're question is a little unclear. What would you like the result to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^[^{}]*(\\{([^}]*)\\})[^{}]*$"); 
string inputStr = "mystring{valueToRaplace}";
string replaceWithThis = "Replace with this";

//change m.Groups[2] to whichever index you want to replace
string final = regex.Replace(inputStr, 
                    new MatchEvaluator(new Func<Match, string>(m => inputStr.Replace(m.Groups[2].Value, replaceWithThis))));
```